# Get json data from controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

Scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getMeterInfo(meter_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("MeterInfo", "Power")',
        data: { meter_id: meter_id},
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        error: function () {
            alert("Error!");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var item = "";
            item += data.sno + " " + data.customer_id + data.city + data.region; //+ more info about meter.

            $("#meter_info").html(item);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#meters").change(function () {
        var meter_id = $("#meters").val();
        getMeterInfo(meter_id);
    });
});
</script>
```

**NOTE:** I know content of success function is not correct. I dont know, What Can I write there.

cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownList("sno", new SelectList(Model, "sno", "meter_name"), "-- Select Meter --", new { id = "meters" })

<table id=meter_info>
</table>
```

Controller

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult MeterInfo(string meter_id)
 {
    int _meter_id = Int32.Parse(meter_id);
    var _meter = entity.TblMeters.Where(x => x.sno == _meter_id).FirstOrDefault();

    return Json(_meter, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Model

```
 public class TblMeters
 {
      int sno;
      int customer_id;
      string city;
      string region;
      .....
 }
```

I want to show my model values (sno,customer_id,city,region, etc...) in a html table. When I debug program, Controller action returns expected data.

1. I dont know How can I show returned data items on table thats name is meter_info.
2. When I run above code, Error function works, not success function.

How can I show data on table? And Why error function works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder is your serialization working correctly. What happens if you change this:

```
return Json(_meter, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

To

```
return Json(new { sno = _meter.sno, customer_id = _meter.customer_id etc. }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Also, it would really help if you could check Developer Toolbar (F12 in most of the browsers) Network tab to check what is the response.

**Update**

You can check how your data serialized. If you are using built-in serializer/deserializer then you can try something like this.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(yourData);
```

With JSON.NET

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourData, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the solution. Is partial view good solution too? Which one Should I prefer?

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi it's a matter of taste and requirements. If you return JSON then you could use the same data for other clients, such as native mobile device app just render it differently. Or you can use it for public API

Comment: in my Meter class there are 25 value. If I use this method, Json function will grow.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi try to serialize your data outside of the return statement then you might notice problems in the serialization process

Comment: @AliRıza Adıyahşi - the benefit of using a partial view is that you don't have to use jQuery to build the HTML from the result, but as Tx3 said, it's more a matter of taste and what you can do with your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify whether or not the success function even gets called with firebug etc...?  Or just old-school by putting an alert('got called!') in there?

And in addition:

1) The following code you posted uses one variable called **item** and another called **items**.  Was that your intention because you are setting the inner html to empty string.

```
    var **item** = "";
    **items** += data.sno + " " + data.customer_id + data.city + data.region; 

    $("#meter_info").html(**item**);
```

2) If you want to loop through the results and add a table row for each result: you would want to use jQuery "each" for that, but on further inspection it looks like you are just displaying one record via this result.  Which is odd that you are using a table to display only one row.

To add one result (of course you may want to divide this into multiple columns):

```
$('#meter_info').append('<tr><td>' + data.sno 
           + ' ' + data.customer_id + data.city + data.region + '</td></tr>'
```

If you wanted to return and append multiple rows:

```
    $.each(data, function(index,data){$('#meter_info').append('<tr><td>' + data.sno 
       + ' ' + data.customer_id + data.city + data.region + '</td></tr>' };
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's an option, I'd suggest using unobtrusive AJAX to accomplish this. It takes a lot of the work and does it for you.

So based on what you are attempting, you'd want to create a strongly typed Partial View that accepts a list of TableMeters as it's model class. (Forgive my lack of Razor, but I prefer C#...)

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<TableMeters>>" %>
    <table>
    <% foreach(TableMeter meter in Model){ %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= meter.sno %></td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
```

Then, on the main page, you'd want something along these lines:

```
<% using(Ajax.BeginForm("MeterInfo", "Power", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "meterTable" })){ %>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("meter_id", new SelectList(Model, "sno", "meter_name"), "-- Select Meter --", new { id = "meters", onchange="$(this).parent().submit()" }) %>
<% } %>

<div id="meterTable">
    <%= Html.Partial("MeterTable", Model.TblMeters) %>
</div>
```

Your controller method can stay mostly the same, but you'll need drop the [HttpGet] and change the return to:

```
return PartialView("MeterTable", _meter);
```

Double check the logic as far as what is getting passed around, I'm not entirely sure what all of your classes look like, but that should do the trick.  When you change the dropdown, it will trigger the "onchange" event, which should submit the containing form. The form will submit via AJAX to the controller.  Note that the name of the dropdown must match the parameter for the controller method.  You can do your filtering like you already have it, and return the list to the partial view.  The partial view will populate, and replace the contents of the div.